# Trouble finding textbox within a generated EPX payment form

Tags: java, selenium

First timer asking a question here.

```
<input type="text" name="account_nbr" value="" maxlength="19"
       autocomplete="off" class="mainTextBox" id="account_nbr" >
```

Here is some simple html that's causing me a headache.
The issue I believe is that this textbox is contained in an EPX CC payment form that is generated on the page after I select a credit card type from a dropdown menu. It isn't in a new window or anything. It's just a form generated within the page.

I've tried waiting using:

```
public static WebElement textbox_CardNumber(WebDriver driver) {
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 15); 
    element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("account_nbr")));
    return element; 
}
```

It times out every time. I've also tried several other times with different xpaths as well but nothing worked (throwing darts). I am pretty novice at selenium and java right now and hope someone else has run into something like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is common that forms provided by 3rd parties will come within an iFrame. iFrames have their own DOM which is seperate from the parent page's DOM. Since Selenium operates on the DOM directly, it will not look within included iFrames.

To see the content, you must switch to the iframe's context with Selenium.

One method of doing this is using driver.switchTo(). WebDriverWait also provides a nice method of doing this.

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt("id or name of the iframe element"));
```

You can use driver.switchTo().defaultContent() at any time to switch back to using the page's primary DOM.